# How to add event to each element generated dynamically in javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am creating  'li' element dynamically through a loop and i m getting problem in assigning event to each element that is generated dynamically.I want to do assign event onclick on each li element that is generated.

Here is the code:

```
var not = [{
  "event": "It's your friend's Birthday. Wish him luck!!!",
  "view": "unread",
  "status": "read",
  "image": "<img src='cake.jpg' style='height:80px';'width:80px'>"
}]

var ids = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"];
var lis = new Array(10);
var i = 0;

for (i; i < not.length; i++) {
  lis[i] = document.createElement("li");
  var obj = document.createTextNode(not[i].event);
  lis[i].appendChild(obj);
  document.body.appendChild(lis[i]);
  lis[i].setAttribute('id', ids[i]);
  var x = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
  x.addEventListener("click", func('ids[i]'));
  document.body.appendChild(ids[i]);

}

function func(a) {
  document.getElementById(a).innerHTML = "hello";
}
```

similarly there are 5 more not objects.

Comment: What is the problem? What is `not`? What is `not[i].event`?

Comment: `x.addEventListener("click", func())` should be `x.addEventListener("click", func)`

Comment: What is not? What is not[i].event?

Comment: not is an object(json). var not = [{
     "event" : "It's your friend's Birthday. Wish him luck!!!",
     "view" : "unread",
     "status" : "read",
     "image" : "<img src='cake.jpg' style='height:80px';'width:80px'>"
    },

Comment: Please include the var not in the code block of you post to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
x.addEventListener("click", func());
```

by

```
x.addEventListener("click", func);
```

If you use `func()` you are calling the function and send the return value of `func()`, instead of passing the function itself.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying actually i wanted to assign events to each of the element generated in a loop itself..is it possible? its not working on every element

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.bind`, to bind value to event listener. When you do

```
x.addEventListener("click", func('ids[i])');
```

1. You are assigning return value of `func` to event listener.
2. `'ids[i]'` is not a variable. Its a string.

Replace following to:

```
x.addEventListener("click", func.bind(ids[i]));
```